# What is the "profile URL" field asking for when deleting an account?

Tags: support

I am trying to delete my profile (from all of the stack exchange) and one of the fields in the "delete account" page is asking for a profile link or profile url. I have no idea what this is and no amount of searching this site has yielded any results, nor is it ever mentioned in the help center section on deleting an account. Either someone tell me what I need enter here or, better yet, one of you moderators make yourself useful and go do it for me. I WANT OUT!!! and if any of you hall monitors gets on here to tell me this is off topic or throw up some obligatory link to help page that doesn't help, so help me GOD i will hunt you down and write "dink" on your forehead in SHARPIE.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay and the confusion. Your account is now scheduled for deletion.

Answer (score 2):

It's the profile page, that you get to when you click on the section of the top bar with the avatar, reputation and badges. Yours is https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/23534/paperstreet and it **should** be automatically populated when you select "I need to delete my user profile" from the "contact us" page.

Since it's Friday night in North America as I write this, it might take a while for Stack Exchange staffers to process the form. After they do, there's a 24 hour grace period to allow for changes of heart (I believe there'll be a button on your profile page saying "cancel deletion" or similar).

---

I have to say, I'd be sorry to see you leave; you've provided some good information here, and I suspect you'd be a star on the upcoming woodworking site. If there's something about the site that the moderators can help resolve (understanding how the site works, conflicts with other users, whatever), please let us know, either in comments here or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement) (or a private chat session if there's something you'd prefer to discuss in confidence).

Comment: I've entered the exact link you provided in the profile url field and it pops up an error that says that's and invalid entry. I appreciate your comments on my past contributions here and I'd be willing to chat with you if you want to know what precipitated my decision to bail, but know that this isn't a cry for help, I'm done here as soon as I can close out my profile.